# Cannot change resolution because drop down menu is flickering on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display-settings

This is happening on a new laptop. I removed Windows 10 Home and replaced it with Windows 10 Enterprise.

I installed these drivers( https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ROG-Strix-SCAR-II/HelpDesk_Download/) and decided to try changing the resolution. That's when I noticed the problem in the image below. I'm not sure when it started occuring. It flickers when idle and it closes instantly when I try to click it.

When I boot in safe mode I don't see this problem anymore. I've been having problems installing Nvidia drivers and I wonder if it's related to that.

[gif of me clicking the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J30dz.gif)

Laptop Specs:

Model: Asus ROG Scar II GL504GV
CPU: Intel Core i7-8750H
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2060 6GB GDDR6
SSD: 512GB PCIE NVMe
HDD: None
RAM: 16GB DDR4 2666MHz RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to post this when I realized I hadn't installed the Asus Bluetooth driver in the link above. So Just before I posted I tried installing it and it fixed my problem. I'm not sure how that's related to the drop down menu but it seems to have worked.

I'm not sure if it's the Bluetooth driver itself that fixed it or if there's another reason.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue. Mine had another symptom on top of what you had in your screenshot. On the taskbar, in the arrow that pops up the additional applications like "Network Internet Access" or whatever app icons that you group in, also flickers.

I checked Device Manager and found out that there's a Generic plug and play USB device with issues. Turns out that one of the USB extension/hub that I was using was the cause. Unplugging that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue..searched the internet for a good 10mins only to find Nothing >:/, after taking a quick breather..I simply did the same fix for "Menu's constantly scrolling" which was to simply sign out and sign back in..fixed the issue so if you having problems changing resolution and more this will work....hopefully you make it here..because I was not making an account to post this...

Side Note even with the flicking menu's you can change resolution simply by pressing the "Down Arrow" for the next resolution..but that took really long for me to switch..to the setting I desired at the time..